# Delphi firebird query - trigger OnFetchRecords

Tags: delphi, firebird

I am looking for a way to 'catch' records being fetched in a query(ibobjects TIBOQuery) component, there doesn't seem to be such event.

I would like to show a label that shows like 'Records fetched 100/Totalrecords 425698', and that label should get updated each time the query fetches more records due to scrolling in the DBGrid.

I have been playing with the 'OnCallBack' event but that doesn't seem to do it, it gets triggered when i fetch all records but not when i fetch the next 50 records.

Does anyone have a idea how to trigger the dataset fetching records?

Comment: It sounds like you are out of luck, but in any case if you really are retreiving 400k+ records in a Sql query, your app design is wrong, imo.

Comment: With all respect but i find it weird to comment on the app design when you don't know what kind of app it is, it's generally a Db Admin tool like ibconsole, IbPhoenix, IbExpert etc

Comment: _FireDAC_ provide _fetch options_ which will allow you to do so.